# understanding the logic of Rotating a N x N matrix

Tags: c++, pointers, matrix

Hi I have started solving C++ questions. One among them is rotating a N x N matrix to a 90 degree clockwise.

below is the code link, that i'm referring to. I had never solved matrix problems in C++/any.

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/turn-an-image-by-90-degree/

```html
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
 
void displayMatrix(unsigned int const *p, unsigned int row, unsigned int col);
void rotate(unsigned int *pS, unsigned int *pD, unsigned int row, unsigned int col);
 
int main()
{
    // declarations
    unsigned int image[][4] = {{1,2,3,4}, {5,6,7,8}, {9,10,11,12}};
    unsigned int *pSource;
    unsigned int *pDestination;
    unsigned int m, n;
 
    // setting initial values and memory allocation
    m = 3, n = 4, pSource = (unsigned int *)image;
    pDestination = (unsigned int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*m*n);
 
    // process each buffer
    displayMatrix(pSource, m, n);
 
    rotate(pSource, pDestination, m, n);
 
    displayMatrix(pDestination, n, m);
 
    free(pDestination);
 
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
 
void displayMatrix(unsigned int const *p, unsigned int r, unsigned int c)
{
    unsigned int row, col;
    printf("\n\n");
 
    for(row = 0; row < r; row++)
    {
        for(col = 0; col < c; col++)
        {
            printf("%d\t", *(p + row * c + col)); // what is this??? couldnt understand this logic?
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
 
    printf("\n\n");
}
 
void rotate(unsigned int *pS, unsigned int *pD, unsigned int row, unsigned int col)
{
    unsigned int r, c;
    for(r = 0; r < row; r++)
    {
        for(c = 0; c < col; c++)
        {
            *(pD + c * row + (row - r - 1)) = *(pS + r * col + c); // not understanding this logic as well.
        }
    }
}
```

could any one please explain more about this logic. I'm not able to resolve few places in the above problems that i have mentioned in the code itself.

Also please let me know the time and space complexity detailed..Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code relies on a two-dimensional array being contiguously stored and treats it as one-dimensional.

The line

```
*(pD + c * row + (row - r - 1)) = *(pS + r * col + c);
```

is equivalent to

```
pD[c][row-r-1] = pS[r][c];
```

Comment: Also note that it is almost always better to write it as above with two indices than to try to outsmart the compiler.

Comment: @ molbdnilo :  thanks for the answer. but still couldnt relate both the statments.. could you please explain more on this?

Also please explain about this statment,
printf("%d\t", *(p + row * c + col));